# Regularity of Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ an open and bounded open set, and let $f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Is it true that the unique weak solution in $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ of the Poisson equation $$-\Delta u = f$$ is in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ (i.e., compactly supported in $\Omega$, or just vanishing on the boundary)?

Comment: Compactly supported in $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true if $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ means smooth functions compactly supported in $\Omega$.

Here is an example. Consider the ball $\Omega=B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function satisfying $\Phi(t)=t$ for $t \le 1$ and $\Phi(t)=2$ for $t\geq 3$. Finally define

$$u(x,y) = \Phi(-\log(x^2+y^2)) \ \ \ \text{for } (x,y) \in \Omega\setminus \{(0,0)\},$$

and $u(0,0)=2$. Then $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ is harmonic in a neigborhood of $\partial \Omega$, hence $f:=-\Delta u$ is smooth with compact support in $\Omega$. On the other hand $u$ is smooth and vanishes on the boundary, but is not compactly supported in $\Omega$.

If your questions is just about regularity, then yes, every weak solution of Poisson's equation with smooth right hand side belongs to $C^\infty(\Omega)$. This is called interior regularity, and does not depend on any properties of the boundary. If you want $u\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$, then you need to assume the boundary is also smooth.

EDIT: Here is an example in dimension $n=1$ to help clarify my additional remarks in the comment section. Suppose that $\Omega = (-2,2)$ and

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1,&\text{if } -1 < x < 1\\
0,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

The fact that $f$ is not smooth is not really an issue for the example, and we could smooth it out without changing the main ideas. The key point is that $f$ is compactly supported. Now let $B_0=(-1,1)$ be the support of $f$. The solution of $-u_0'' = f$ in $B_0$ with $u_0(-1)=0=u_0(1)$ is

$$u_0(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}x^2.$$

The solution of $-u'' = f$ in $\Omega$ with $u(-2)=0=u(2)$ cannot be the zero extension of $u_0$, since $u$ must be $C^1$. In fact, the solution is the $C^1$ function

$$u(x) = \begin{cases}
x+2,&\text{if } -2 < x < -1\\
\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}x^2,&\text{if } -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
-x+2,&\text{if } 1 < x < 2.\end{cases}$$

Notice that $u$ is not compactly supported and does not agree with $u_0$ (it is a coincidence that $u(x)=u_0(x) + 1$ for $x \in B_0$, and this will not be true in general).

Basically, you cannot localize solutions of elliptic equations in the way you would like. The solution at any point $x$ depends on $f$ throughout the entire domain (think Green's functions).

Comment: Hi Jeff, I was thinking about the following argument, that seems to be in contradiction with your example. I am not able to figure out mistakes in both your example and in my argument. So there is something really stupid that I am not considering. Take a look:

Comment: Call $B_0$ the support of $f$ which is contained in $B(0,1)$ and consider the unique solution in $H_0^1(B_0)$ of the Poisson equation $-\Delta u_0=f$, and the unique solution $u$ in $H_0^1(B(0,1))$ of the Poisson equation $-\Delta u=f$. The link between the two solutions must be (by construction) that $u$ is the extension by zero of $u_0$. That seems to be in contradiction with your example which vanishes just on the boundary and not in a neighborhood of it.

Comment: The zero extension of $u_0$ is not $C^2$, but is in $H^1_0(B(0,1))$, so you have to interpret the solution in the weak sense. The test functions used for weak solutions of $-\Delta u_0 = f$ in $B_0$ must be compactly supported in $B_0$, while the test functions for $-\Delta u = f$ in $B(0,1)$ need only be compactly supported in $B(0,1)$. The error in your reasoning is in assuming the class of test functions for each problem is the same. I'll add an example to my answer where there is more space.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Now everything is clear ;-)

Comment: No problem at all! It is a subtle issue, and certainly not a stupid mistake.